# DFS Traversal in graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, depth-first-search

I am trying to do dfs traversal using recursive call, My Graph, and `vector<int>visited` are global variables. `num_v` variable corresponds to number of vertices,`num_e` corresponds to number of edges I tried calling two DFS calls in main, but my output matches to the correct DFS order for the first case. and it gives incorrect out for the other, kindly help where I'm getting wrong in the implementation of it.

**sample input:** first line is a number of vertices and number of edges. next, each line is directed nodes between two-point.

```
5 5
1 2
2 4
4 5
5 3
1 3
```

**expected output:**

```
1 2 4 5 3
2 4 5 3
```

**my wrong output**

```
1 2 4 5 3
2
```

code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
int mx=1e5;
//int num_v;
vector<vector<int>>Graph(mx);
vector<int>visited;
void dfs(int v,vector<int>&vec){
    visited[v]=1;
    vec.push_back(v);
    for(int neigh:Graph[v]){
        if(visited[neigh]!=1){
            dfs(neigh,vec);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int num_v;int num_e;
    cin>>num_v>>num_e;
    visited.resize(num_v + 1);
    for(int i=0;i<num_e;i++){
        int u,v;
        cin>>u>>v;
        Graph[u].push_back(v);
    }
    vector<int>vec;
    dfs(1,vec);
    for(auto x:vec){
        cout<<x<<" ";
    }
    visited.clear();
    cout<<endl;
    vector<int>tt;
    dfs(2,tt);
    for(auto y:tt){
        cout<<y<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen with this line `vector<int>visited(num_v+1);` but I can tell you for certain that initializing your vector with the uninitialized variable `num_v` is a recipe for disaster.  Turn on all compiler warnings.  Instead of sizing the vector during init, you should size it _after_ you've actually got a value for `num_v`.  _e.g._ `visited.resize(num_v + 1);`  You should also consider passing `visited` as a reference parameter to your function instead of relying on global variables.

Comment: Please give a simple example where the expected and actual outputs differ (the simpler, the easier to debug). When you debugged your code in this case, at what point did the values of your variables start to differ from your expectations?

Comment: paddy's comment should be the right answer, suggest closing this.

Comment: @paddy sir i tried implementing the same but again it outputs the same.

Comment: For the first `dfs` call, `visited` is most likely a pretty large non-empty vector (since you passed a random garbage value for its length). The program already exhibits undefined behavior, but likely by accident it happens to work. For the second `dfs` call, `visited` is empty (since you called `clear` on it). `visited[v]=1` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: @Igor i haven't passed random value to the length of visited, the length corresponds to a total number of vertices.

Comment: You have `int num_v; vector<int>visited(num_v+1);` At the time you use `num_v`, it's not yet initialized. You read a value into it later, but you never actually use that value.

Comment: @igor sir,i implemented paddy's instruction,still, it outputs the same.

Comment: Edit your question to show the modified code. I for one can't help with code I can't see.  That said - do you realize that `visited.clear()` makes `visited` empty, of size zero and not `num_v`?

Comment: @Igor sir,i have edited it,yeah i do realise but i thought visited.clear() should not change size of vector visited from num_v to zero. i thought all values in visited will become just zero after clear.

Comment: You thought incorrectly. Print `visited.size()` after `clear()` and see for yourself.

Comment: @igor yeah thank you so much,i tried to resize visited to num_v back and got the expected output.